# How to get the x y coordinates from a line of a png image and use it in a shiny app

Tags: r, image, shiny, slider, png

This is a follow-up question to this [Color an area with a sliderInput in a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186960/color-an-area-with-a-sliderinput-in-a-shiny-app/75287166?noredirect=1#comment133076407_75287166)

Suppose I have this image:

[image]

How could I apply this solution by @ismirsehregal to this picture. I think I have to put the x and y from the esophagus to the code, but I don't know how to get the x and y of the esophagues (green in the picture):

Code from [Color an area with a sliderInput in a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186960/color-an-area-with-a-sliderinput-in-a-shiny-app/75287166?noredirect=1#comment133076407_75287166)

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

DF <- data.frame(
    x = c(cos(seq(0.01, 10, 0.01)) * 1000:1 + 1000, cos(seq(0.01, 10, 0.01)) * 1000:1 + 1500),
    y = rep(1:1000, 2),
    id = c(rep("trace_1", 1000), rep("trace_2", 1000))
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  column(
    2,
    noUiSliderInput(
      inputId = "noui2",
      label = "Slider vertical:",
      min = 0,
      max = 1000,
      step = 50,
      value = c(100, 400),
      margin = 100,
      orientation = "vertical",
      direction = c("rtl"),
      width = "100px",
      height = "350px"
    )
  ),
  column(4, plotlyOutput("plot")),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(input$noui2)
  
  plotDF <- reactive({
    plotDF <- DF[DF$y %in% input$noui2[1]:input$noui2[2], ]
    plotDF$id <- paste0("filtered_", plotDF$id)
    plotDF
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(
        rbind(DF, plotDF()),
        x = ~ x,
        y = ~ y,
        split = ~ id,
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines",
        color = I("black"),
        fillcolor = 'red',
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) |> style(fill = 'tonexty', traces = 2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I think your question is "how to identify the x/y coordinates from a particular area of a PNG", is that right? I think this means this is about image processing (and understand the raster of an image) and not about shiny.

Comment: You could get a decent approximation from doing run-length encoding on the pixels, row-wise. In the middle section of your image, each row of pixels will be white-black-white-black, and the oesophagus will be the middle white section. The rle will tell you the start and end position of the white portion (I.e. its x co-ordinates), and the row number you are on will be the y co-ordinates. You might need to do this to a cropped section of the image to avoid the other structures, but it would at least be a decent approximation. Perhaps you could tweak the end result manually?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. r2evans thanks for this insight. @Allan Cameron could you please show how to do it rle on pixels. Many thanks!

Comment: For @AllanCameron approach with `rle` it would be useful to provide a 'pre-slider' .png as 'data' (as we so often ask for), then a distance measure could differentiate esophagus from duodenum (exiting the stomach)...and generally [pixel matrix from png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800687/how-to-get-a-pixel-matrix-from-grayscale-image-in-r) for the other part of the slog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following approach doesn't meet the title of your question, but it shows the procedure I mentioned in your previous post.

You will need to save a modified png file (transparent esophagus - edited with [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)'s "fuzzy select tool") in your apps `www` folder for this to work (please find it below).

I'm now using `plotlyProxyInvoke` to update the data without re-rendering the plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyWidgets)

slider_min <- 0
slider_max <- 45
lower_slider_value <- 5
upper_slider_value <- 18
x_position_trace_1 <- 40
x_position_trace_2 <- 50

DF <- data.frame(
  x = c(rep(x_position_trace_1, 2), rep(x_position_trace_2, 2)),
  y = rep(c(lower_slider_value, upper_slider_value), 2),
  id = c(rep("trace_1", 2), rep("trace_2", 2))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  column(
    2,
    noUiSliderInput(
      inputId = "noui2",
      label = "Slider vertical:",
      min = slider_min,
      max = slider_max,
      step = 1L,
      value = c(lower_slider_value, upper_slider_value),
      margin = 1,
      orientation = "vertical",
      width = "100px",
      height = "350px"
    )
  ),
  column(4, plotlyOutput("myPlot", height = "800px")),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(input$noui2)
  
  output$myPlot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(
      DF,
      x = ~ x,
      y = ~ y,
      split = ~ id,
      type = "scatter",
      mode = "lines",
      color = I("white"),
      fillcolor = 'red',
      showlegend = FALSE
    ) |> layout(
      images = list(
        list(
          source =  "/esophagus.png",
          xref = "x",
          yref = "y",
          x = 0,
          y = -16,
          sizex = 93,
          sizey = 93,
          sizing = "stretch",
          opacity = 1,
          layer = "above"
        )
      ),
      plot_bgcolor  = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
      paper_bgcolor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
      xaxis = list(
        zerolinecolor = '#ffff',  
        zerolinewidth = 2,  
        gridcolor = 'ffff',
        range = list(0, 100)),  
      yaxis = list(
        zerolinecolor = '#ffff',  
        zerolinewidth = 2,  
        gridcolor = 'ffff',
        range = list(80, -20)
        # or autorange = "reversed"
        )  
    ) |> style(fill = 'tonexty', traces = 2)
  })
  
  myPlotProxy <- plotlyProxy("myPlot", session)
  
  observe({
    plotlyProxyInvoke(myPlotProxy, "restyle", list(x = list(rep(x_position_trace_1, 2), rep(x_position_trace_2, 2)), y = list(input$noui2, input$noui2)), list(0, 1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

---

Image for the `www` folder - save as "esophagus.png".

To visualize the transparent area (grey) open the image in a new browser tab (chrome):

[image: transparent_esophagus]

---

**Edit:** Here is another lightweight approach without using {plotly}.

This isn't perfectly aligned yet and it might make sense to work wit `%` instead of `px`, however it shows the principle:

We can simply provide the esophagus image with a red background image and modify the css properties `background-size` and `background-position-y`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  br(),
  column(
    2,
    noUiSliderInput(
      inputId = "noui2",
      label = "Slider vertical:",
      min = 0,
      max = 1000,
      step = 50,
      value = c(100, 400),
      margin = 100,
      orientation = "vertical",
      direction = c("rtl"),
      width = "100px",
      height = "350px"
    )
  ),
  column(
    4,
    tags$img(
      id = "esophagus",
      height = 1000,
      width = "100%",
      src = "/esophagus.png",
      style = "background-image: url(red_background.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 30%; background-position-y: 40%;"
    )
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res2 <- renderPrint(input$noui2)
  
  observeEvent(input$noui2, {
    runjs(paste0('$("#esophagus").css("background-size", "100% ', input$noui2[2] - input$noui2[1], 'px");'))
    runjs(paste0('$("#esophagus").css("background-position-y", "', 1000 - input$noui2[2], 'px");'))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Save as "red_background.png" in your `www` folder:

[image: red_background]

Comment: This is fantastic once again. I saw it already yesterday, but was able to check it today.

Comment: Info: I had to change x = 0 to x=40 in the layout of the server section.

Comment: @TarJae I just added the variables x_trace_1 and x_trace_2 to create a wider colored rectangle in the background if needed (depending on the position of the foreground image). Cheers

Comment: Thank you amazing. could you give me an advice how to change the slider to rang 0 to 45 that will cover the red background. So actually min = 0 and max is 1000. I would like to have the range 0 to 45. I know how to alter the range, but how to I alter the png and the background?.

Comment: @TarJae regarding the plotly approach?

Comment: You should be able to do it yourself. You need to modify the image size, position and the axes ranges in the `plot_ly` call accordingly (I'm currently only on mobile).

Comment: thanks that was a good hint!!! No worries!

Comment: I have change this: `x_trace_1 <- 170
x_trace_2 <- 210
lower_slider_start <- (100/1000)*45
upper_slider_start <- (400/1000)*45` and this:     `noUiSliderInput(
      inputId = "noui2",
      label = "Slider vertical:",
      min = 0,
      max = 45,
      step = 1,
      value = c(lower_slider_start, upper_slider_start),
      margin = 1,
      orientation = "vertical",
      direction = c("rtl"),
      width = "100px",
      height = "350px"
    )`

Comment: How can I now adapt the red area to the same values. It works but moving the sliders moves the red area only a minimal distance(which is obvious) but I cant find a way to set the values for the red area?! If it is to much I can start a new question. Sorry for stealing your valuable time. But I can see the finish line and would like to complete!

Comment: Thank you very much. I accpted the bounty for you already. So I am very grateful. Maybe you could give an advice for 2 remaining things. 1. If we change the windows size the whole app does not work (so I have to fix the size?) and 2. I would like to revert the slider input that kind that zero is on top and 45 is on bottom (this is feasible!) but how would we then revert the red area? You have already done enough so far and I am really happy. But maybe and only if it is easy to solve invest your time, otherwise I thank you very much again.

Comment: Regarding the window size change `sizing = "contain"` to `"stretch"`.

Comment: @TarJae please check another edit. The y-axis is now reversed.

Comment: I am deeply impressed and grateful.