# How to crop images circular in gt tables in Shiny Apps?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, gt

For one of the last week's `TidyTuesday` challenge, I am trying to make a Shiny app on NHL Player's data. Here is the code so far;

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(cropcircles)


nhl_rosters <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2024/2024-01-09/nhl_rosters.csv')


colnames(nhl_rosters) <- c("Team Code", "Season", "Position Type", "Player ID", "Headshot", "First Name", "Last Name", "Sweater Number", "Position Code", "Shoots Catches", 
                           "Height in Inches", "Weight in Pounds", "Height in Centimeters", "Weight in Kilograms", "Birth Date", "Birth City", "Birth Country", "Birth Province")

nhl_rosters <- nhl_rosters %>%
  relocate("Headshot",  "Player ID", "Season", "First Name", "Last Name")


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = html("<b><span style='; font-family: Instrument Serif'>NHL Players' Analysis</span></b>")),
                    dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"), startExpanded = TRUE),
                                                 virtualSelectInput(inputId = "show_vars", label = "Columns in the dataset to show:", 
                                                                    names(nhl_rosters), selected = names(nhl_rosters), showDropboxAsPopup = TRUE, 
                                                                    popupDropboxBreakpoint = "3000px", width = "100%", multiple = TRUE, dropboxWrapper = "body"),
                                                 sliderInput(inputId = "show_vars_weight", label = "Choose a range for weight (in kg):", 
                                                             min(nhl_rosters$`Weight in Kilograms`, na.rm = TRUE), max(nhl_rosters$`Weight in Kilograms`, na.rm = TRUE), value = c(57, 120)),
                                                 # pickerInput("show_vars", "Columns in the dataset to show:", multiple = TRUE, names(nhl_rosters), selected = names(nhl_rosters)),
                                                 menuItem("Widget"))),
                    dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                                                   fluidPage(valueBoxOutput("approvalBox1"),
                                                             valueBoxOutput("approvalBox2"),
                                                             valueBoxOutput("approvalBox3"),
                                                             h2("Canadian NHL Players", style = "font-family: Playfair Display;"), 
                                                             gt_output(outputId = "mytable1"),
                                                             downloadButton(outputId = "download_csv", label = "Download CSV"))))
                                  )
                    )
                                                   
                                        
server <- function(input, output) {
  # choose columns to display
  nhl_rosters_total <- nhl_rosters %>%
    slice(1:100) %>%
    mutate(Season = str_replace(Season, "^(....)", "\\1-")) 
  nhl_rosters_selected <- reactive({
    selected_columns <- input$show_vars
    nhl_rosters_total %>%
      select(all_of(selected_columns)) 
  })
  output$mytable1 <- render_gt(
    gt(nhl_rosters_selected() %>% 
         filter(`Weight in Kilograms` >= input$show_vars_weight[1] & `Weight in Kilograms` <= input$show_vars_weight[2])) %>%
      opt_interactive(use_search = TRUE, use_filters = TRUE, use_resizers = TRUE, use_highlight = TRUE,
                      use_compact_mode = TRUE, use_text_wrapping = FALSE, use_page_size_select = TRUE) %>%
      gt_img_rows(Headshot, img_source = "web", height = 30) %>%
      cols_align(align = "center", columns = everything()) 
  ) 
  output$download_csv <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("nhl_players-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      selected_data <- nhl_rosters_selected() %>% filter(`Weight in Kilograms` >= input$show_vars_weight[1] & `Weight in Kilograms` <= input$show_vars_weight[2])
      write.csv(selected_data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  output$approvalBox1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      nrow(nhl_rosters_selected() %>% select(`Player ID`) %>% distinct()), "Number of players in the dataset", icon = icon("list", lib = "glyphicon"),
      color = "aqua"
    )
  })
  weight_data <- nhl_rosters_total %>% select(`Player ID`, `Weight in Kilograms`) %>% distinct() %>% select(`Weight in Kilograms`)
  output$approvalBox2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      round(mean(weight_data$`Weight in Kilograms`, na.rm = TRUE), 1), "Average Weight (in kg)",
      color = "yellow"
    )
  })
  height_data <- nhl_rosters_total %>% select(`Player ID`, `Height in Centimeters`) %>% distinct() %>% select(`Height in Centimeters`)
  output$approvalBox3 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      round(mean(height_data$`Height in Centimeters`, na.rm = TRUE), 1), "Average Height (in cm)",
      color = "purple"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I would like to achieve is to crop images in `Headshot` column so that they should be in the circular format, rather than being in the rectangular format. Note that, the column have associating urls for png files and I do not want to save them on my local computer and then crop the images circular. In other words, I am looking for a solution to crop them circular, without saving images on my local computer. How can  I make that happen? Thank you for your time beforehand.

Comment: I'd suggest to create an image with a transparent circular area and display it on top of the NHL Player's image. Same logic as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420578/how-to-get-the-x-y-coordinates-from-a-line-of-a-png-image-and-use-it-in-a-shiny/75448129#75448129).